# Why is $(document).blur() and $(document).focus() not working with Safari or Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making a counter which counts down when document is on focus. It stops counting down when it's on blur.

It is working in FF, but with Safari and Chrome, the counter doesn't work at all.

Is there a compatibility problem with Safari/Chrome?

All I'm using is `$(document).blur()` and `$(document).focus()`, and there are both within a `$(document).ready()` block.

```
var tm;
$(document).ready(function(){   

        var seconds = 50;
        $('#timer').html(seconds);
        countdown();

    $(window).focus(function(){
         function countdown(){ 
         if (seconds > 0) {
            seconds--; 
            $('#timer').text(seconds);
            tm = setTimeout(countdown,1000);
            }
        if (seconds<=0){ 
            $('#timer').text('Go');
            }   
        }); 



    $(window).blur(function(){
        clearTimeout(tm);
        seconds++;
        $('#timer').text(seconds);

    });
});
```

Answer (score 13):

I've always used `$(window).focus()` and `$(window).blur()`. Try these instead.

Also, note that in FF and IE the "focus" event fires on ~document load, while in Chrome and Safari it only fires if the window had lost focus before and now it has regained it.

**UPD:** Now as you pasted your code, I reworked it to (hopefully) fit your purpose:

```
var tm;
var seconds = 50;
var inFocus = true;

function countdown() {
    if (seconds > 0) {
        seconds--;
    }

    if (seconds <= 0) {
        $('#timer').text('Go');
    }
    else {
        $('#timer').text(seconds);
        tm = setTimeout(countdown, 1000);
    }
}

$(function() {
    $('#timer').html(seconds);
    countdown();

    $(window).focus(function() {
         if(!inFocus) {
             countdown();
         }
    });

    $(window).blur(function() {
        inFocus = false;
        clearTimeout(tm);
        seconds++;
        $('#timer').text(seconds);
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I have tried your way. It only works for the second focus. But the counter doesn't start on (window).focus(). Is there a way to solve that, even if it takes more code? Thanks a lot

Comment: I already explained the reason for not counting the first focus in Chrome. I updated my answer with a cross-browser solution (or so I think).

Comment: Hi thanks for your solution. I just didn't understand what I'm supposed to put in the if statement. what's the difference between `// count = 1;` and `// count++;`? THanks a lot for your help. Regards

Comment: @alexx0186 the `if` state executes only once at document load. It defines the initial value for the counter in case the browser is Chrome or Safari. And `count++` executes each time the window gets focus, incrementing the counter. I'm not sure if = 1 and ++ is what you need, because you didn't describe in detail how you want your counter to work.

Comment: Hi there, I included my counter in my post. As you can see, both are wrapped in the ready() function. But I don't know what to put in your if statement. Thanks a lot for your help. Regards

Comment: @alexx0186 now I understand what you're trying to achieve. Take a look at the code in my updated answer.

Comment: Thank your for your response. I tried your way, but it doesn't have any effect on the counter in Safari/Chrome. WHen I refocus on it, the counter goes faster. I will try to work out a solution and will let you know if I find one. Thanks a lot. Regards

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using? It works for me with 1.7: http://jsfiddle.net/Shedal/UEAA7/

Comment: I'm using 1.7 as well. In jsfiddle, it works when I focus on another iframe of jsfiddle, but not when I focus out of my browser.. Will get back to you with a solution. THanks a lot

Comment: Thanks for this - I couldn't get `$(document).blur()` when leaving a page to work on android browser but this worked perfectly.